# p5 resize window without clearing the background

Tags: p5.js

The following code makes use of the p5dom add-on to position the canvas in the centre of the window. To dynamically resize the canvas I'm using the windowResized() function. I want to keep the background function in setup. How do I prevent the background colour from clearing when I resize the window? Many thanks.

```js
var cnv;

function centerCanvas() {
  var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
  var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
  cnv.position(x, y);
}

function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  centerCanvas();
  background(255, 0, 200);
}

function draw(){

}

function windowResized() {
  centerCanvas();
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply set the background in the `windowResized` function.

```
function windowResized() {
  centerCanvas();
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight)
  background(255, 0, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might do is draw everything to a buffer instead of directly to the screen. The `createGraphics()` function is your friend here. From [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics):

```js
var pg;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100);
  pg = createGraphics(100, 100);
}
function draw() {
  background(200);
  pg.background(100);
  pg.noStroke();
  pg.ellipse(pg.width/2, pg.height/2, 50, 50);
  image(pg, 50, 50);
  image(pg, 0, 0, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.js"></script>
```

You would want to draw everything to a buffer, and then when the screen is resized, redraw that buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by adding the background function to the draw one too.

Try this:

```
var cnv;

function centerCanvas() {
  var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
  var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
  cnv.position(x, y);
}

function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  centerCanvas();
  background(255, 0, 200);
}

function draw(){
  //HERE:
  background(255, 0, 200);
}

function windowResized() {
  //(you can add it here too...)
  centerCanvas();
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative method, you could use CSS to edit the dimensions using something similar to the following:

```
<style>
    canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input